# Flash CC publish direct to iPad and get Installation Error: ApplicationVerificationFailed

Tags: ios, flash, air, flash-cc

[image]

I'm in Flash CC... I've created a certificate and provisioning profile for app development, but when I try to publish to the device via the AIR 3.8 for iOS, it processes for about 1min30, and then throws up this error. I'm not sure how to fix it or what could be causing it. I've chosen an app id com.*mycompany*.*myappname* for the provisioning profile... does my flash file need to incorporate that structure anywhere?

Any help appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You need to do a few things (some of which you may have already done, just outlining them all):

1. Create a development certificate, convert it to a .p12 as instructed by Adobe
2. Create an app in the portal.
3. Add your device's UDID to the portal. You **must** use iTunes or Xcode to get this. As of iOS 7, the API used to grab the UDID on the device is removed so any app that claims to do it is returning a false UDID (false UDIDs will start with a bunch of "F"'s, I believe)
4. Create your provisioning profile. Make sure it is a development profile and that it includes your device's UDID and the appropriate App
5. I am unsure if you still have to do this, but you used to have to enable developer mode on device. This may have been done away with in iOS 7, however, as I cannot find the setting on my iPad
6. When compiling, your app **must** use the *exact* id that the App you created in step 2 did

Extra Tips:

1. Avoid doing WiFi debugging. It works, but not well. Stick to USB debug
2. If you have a previous version of the app on your device, try deleting it (long press the icon, hit the X)
3. Make sure your version number is valid (should be x.y.z, where x, y, and z are all a number between 0 and 999)

Some of that is obvious, but make sure you follow it all.

Answer (score 0):

i had the same issue and the points given above didn't solved it... after banging my head for two days i deleted the Entitlement tag from the project xml file..and that solved it digging deeper i found that the issue was i had a key in it beta-reports-active and that only works for Store Submission